# Is it safe to use a microwave sterilizer to sterilize BPA-free baby bottles?

Tags: feeding, bottle-feeding

There is lots of debate regarding microwaving plastics, even if they are BPA-free.

Curious if there is a definitive risk of using a microwave sterilizer (steriliser) (such as the [Avent](http://www.philips.ca/c/avent-baby-preparing-for-feeding/scf271_07/prd/en/)) vs. using an electric steam sterilizer (also made by [Avent](http://www.philips.ca/c/avent-baby-preparing-for-feeding/110v-scf274_30/prd/en/)) with BPA-free bottles.

Comment: This may be more suited for http://skeptics.stackexchange.com . Anyway microwaves only heat the water so the risk is the same in both cases imho.

Comment: What is the concern about microwaving plastics, when it's not BPA?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's enough research in the matter to make a judgement, studies on these types of things take years, and often contradict each other. I'd be on the safe side and use an electric steam sterilizer as I don't know the answer. there's other good reasons for using an electric one:

- They are nearly silent, and microwaves are noisy
- They are a bit more efficient than microwaves. Microwaves are an expensive way to boil water, which is all that sterilization is about really